# Highstock - How to add point if I have different data on main chart and navigator

Tags: highcharts

I want to have data on the chart with scale 1 hour for point and have navigator data with scale 1 day per point.
At the same time I want to add new points to the chart in real time.

When I run my example:
https://jsfiddle.net/antongrinenko/aj7m2euk/3/

```
$(function () {

var val = 0;
function generateValue() {
    val++;
    if (val > 5) {
        val = 0;
    }
    return val;
}

function generateData(backInDays, pointDuration) {
    var points = [];
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - backInDays);

    for (var i = d.getTime(); i<new Date().getTime(); i += pointDuration) {
        points.push([i, generateValue()]);
    }
    return points;
};

var weekData = generateData(30, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); //1 day per point
var oneDayData = generateData(1, 1000 * 60 * 60); //1 hour per point

$('#chart').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'SomeData',
        data: oneDayData
    }],
     navigator : {
         adaptToUpdatedData: false,
         series: {
            data: weekData
         },
     },
    scrollbar: {
        liveRedraw: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        floor: 0
    }
});

setInterval(function() {
    $('#chart').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([new Date().getTime(), generateValue()]);
}, 2000);
});
```

all works fine. But when I scroll a litte left and then back to right main chart stops updating with new points.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: adaptToUpdatedData false and redraw false

Answer (score 0):

try commenting adaptToUpdatedData: false,  working well

Comment: Can't do this, because if I scroll navigator left to see historical data then it automatically go back when new point comes.